# Are there any risks to a drive ( ssd ) working with very large directory which is accessed frequently?

Tags: ssd

I hope this is the correct place to ask such a question.

I am working on a project where I need to process a very large amount of java files. Into the millions. I believe the total file size of all file to be processed to be between 20 - 60 GIG. I may access all these files multiple times between 5 - 30 times or more,I would not modifying them just reading them ( static code analyse).

I am doing this on a personal MacBook with an internal 128GIG SSD. A friend jokingly said should be careful not to "thrash it to death", and avoid to many write operations. Is there any risks my drive?

Is using my drive in this manner increasing any risks more than standard daily use home office computer ).

The project should not necessarily fill the drive.

Comment: SSDs have a write limit which might be what your friend was referring to. You'll need to look up your SSD specs to see what it is. Keep in mind that you'll not come anywhere near reaching it and the limit isn't guaranteed but more of a estimate.

Answer (score 1):

It is never,ever safe to fill up a drive. Drive data gets corrupted this way and data is lost.

You need a bigger drive - large enough to have 25% free space at all times. This is a rule I work by. Others have different views, but I like to be careful

Your OS may need space to update so add that in as well.

Comment: Thanks , say I left more than 25% free space , is there still any risks to my drive than normal usage ( home laptop ). My project may turn out needing less space than expected

Comment: If you keep a buffer of 25% free, you are fine, but always keep watch on it.

Comment: "25% free space at all times" Rubbish. I've been running my laptop with 10% free space for a long time on the system drive (I do have other drives available for data).

Comment: I have been at this for decades. 10% works of course, but then you need to keep a tighter eye on disk usage

Comment: Please read [How Much Free Space Should You Leave on Your Windows PC?](https://www.howtogeek.com/324956/how-much-free-space-should-you-leave-on-your-windows-pc/)

Comment: Probably not as long as me. I've been running Windows since the early 80's. I think I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I am not critical of your comments, but I have seen systems (including servers) screw up doing this.

Comment: I have editing the originally question , I was talking more of the risks of frequent access of a very large directory on a drive and if there was any increased risk over standard office use. Without 'filling' the drive

Comment: Reads are free on SSDs, an SSD can go into a Read only status, whiles Writes are limited on SSDs.  The 25% unused number is indeed rubbish.  You might be able to update your OS which would be unwise, it certainly isn’t unsafe (for your data), like this answer suggests

Comment: I was more worried about the drive itself, I wasn't actually aware of the write limits on SSDs until now. In theory I should be writing once , and then doing many read operations so It sounds like I should be fine as you say

Comment: @Ramhound *"Reads are free on SSDs"* -- Almost, but do a google search for "NAND read disturb error", e.g. https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-10428.  Note that the solution involves an erase+write cycle.

Comment: @sawdust - I didn’t find any search result I would feel comfortable actually clicking on.

Comment: @Ramhound *"I didn’t find any search result I would feel comfortable actually clicking on"* -- Why are you scared of Wikipedia.org?  Try https://superuser.com/search?q=%22read+disturb%22

Comment: @sawdust - You said Google it so I did!

Comment: @John I to am highly skeptical of your claims if reduced reliability of drives > 75% full.  About the strongest argument I can posit is more space allows better wear levelling, but I dont see that that kicking in at 75% - it would be fairly linear and is more an issue for writes then reads.

Comment: Overfilling a drive does not reduce its reliability.  Going past 100% can corrupt data. I have seen it happen. That was my point. It doesn't affect reliability. I have seen the same issue (overfilling) on hard drives.  You may think my buffer is too big, but I am happy with it.